# Listbox filtered dynamically by textbox is recording/saving wrong value

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, listbox

I have a textbox that dynamically filters a listbox on the same form as you type.  The listbox filters perfectly, but the selected value is not saving correctly.  For example, if you click on the fourth value after filtering the listbox and then close the form, it actually saves what would have been the fourth value had the list not been filtered.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
'CODE THAT HANDLES WHAT HAPPENS WHEN THE USER TYPES IN THE SEARCH BOX
    Dim strFullList       As String
    Dim strFilteredList   As String


    If blnSpace = False Then
        Me.Refresh 'refresh to make sure the text box changes are actually available to use

        'specify the default/full rowsource for the control
        strFullList = "SELECT [Project ID], [Project Name] FROM [Admin: Projects] ORDER BY [Project Name];"
        'specify the way you want the rowsource to be filtered based on the user's entry
        strFilteredList = "SELECT [Project ID], [Project Name] FROM [Admin: Projects] WHERE [Project Name] LIKE ""*" & Me.txtSearch.Value & "*"" ORDER BY [Project Name]"

        'run the search
        fLiveSearch Me.txtSearch, Me.lstItems, strFullList, strFilteredList, Me.txtCount
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
'NECESSARY TO IDENTIFY IF THE USER IS HITTING THE SPACEBAR
'IN WHICH CASE WE WANT TO IGNORE THE INPUT

    On Error GoTo err_handle

    If KeyAscii = 32 Then
        blnSpace = True
    Else
        blnSpace = False
    End If


    Exit Sub
    err_handle:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Else
        MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description & _
        vbCrLf & "Error " & Err.Number & "(" & Erl & ")"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_GotFocus()
' USED TO REMOVE THE PROMPT IF THE CONTROL GETS FOCUS
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.txtSearch.Value = "(type to search)" Then
        Me.txtSearch.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtSearch_LostFocus()
' USED TO ADD THE PROMPT BACK IN IF THE CONTROL LOSES FOCUS
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.txtSearch.Value = "" Then
        Me.txtSearch.Value = "(type to search)"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
End Sub
```

I've inherited this database and am trying to fix up areas that are not working.  I'm definitely a novice and I can't seem to figure out where the error might be in the code that is causing the wrong value to save to the record.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
'run the search
fLiveSearch Me.txtSearch, Me.lstItems, strFullList, strFilteredList,  Me.txtCount
```

With

```
me.lstitems.rowsourcetype = "Table/Query"
me.lstitems.rowsource = strfilteredlist
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, John.  Unfortunately, when I replace that code the search-as-you-type no longer works.

Comment: Add `me.refresh` ?